# How to remove k__BackingField in XML Data

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I am receiving a xml data from a service which has 'k_BackingField' in each of its elements.

```
{

  "<UserId>k__BackingField": "b5184b32-0d88-49e7-ba98-afbc96e47b7e",

  "<Date>k__BackingField": "2016-05-11T13:40:36.6542578+01:00",

  "<Resources>k__BackingField": [

    {

      "<Type>k__BackingField": "Num",

      "<Id>k__BackingField": "978000940016736",

      "<IsDeleted>k__BackingField": false

    }

  ]

}
```

I came to know when the WCF service method has [DataMember][DataContract] it would give proper XML format data but when the method uses [Serializable] alone it gives XML data with K_BackingField in each elements.

I will be storing this data which actually should be in a clean XML without k__BackingField.
How do we remove this using C# ?

Comment: This looks more like JSON than XML?!?

Comment: oops sorry..i had both and i got confused

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use auto-properties, use properties with explicit private variables as backend. If you don't, then the compiler creates those k__BackingField to hold the property value for you.

Don't:

```
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

Use:

```
private string _myProperty;
public string MyProperty
{ 
    get { return _myProperty; } 
    set { _myProperty = value; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @oscar! It worked fine.I was able to retrieve without k_BackingField.

Answer (score 5):

you should add `[DataContract]` to your class;

```
[Serializable, DataContract]
public class TestObject
{
  [DataMember]
  public Boolean Value { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public String Text{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add [DataContract] Attribute to your class

Answer (score -1):

you can use auto property

```
public int MyProperty { get; set; }
```

but you need add the attribute to the class

```
[Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObject]
public class MyClass
{
   public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```